# Time is not right in online version

Tags: c#, html

On my website i show people the time when they open my page. So when they opened it at 4/29/2013 10:09 AM it wil show: 4/29/2013 10:09:14 AM

This all is working fine on my localversion.

But now i have my website online and the time is showing with 5 minutes delay. 
I opened it at: 4/29/2013 10:10 AM it shows me: 29-4-2013 10:05:19

Who can help me with showing the right time online. 
The time i want to show needs to be the local time.

The code:

```
        <td>Capture Time:</td> // label
            <td>@DateTime.Now.ToString()</td>
```

Comment: This will probably be due to the time on the server being different from the time on your machine which one is the most correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The time you are showing is server time ... and you are expecting it to be the same as local time.

If your server is in a different timezone than your client machine, the time shown will be different.

You may want to consider using javascript and do this on the client instead.

Or show the server time in a standard format like UTC and the client can try to determine the difference from local time.

Answer (score 1):

DateTime.Now will show you server datetime. If your server & you are located in same timezone, then I think your local system time is different from server datetime.

Also, if your server is in different timezone then you should consider converting in your timezone before showing datetime on the UI.

[Convert Time in Different TimeZones in ASP.NET](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=593)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's displaying in a different format (`dd-MM-yyyy` while you want `MM/dd/yyyy`). Make sure your culture is set correctly in the web.config on your production server:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8"
        culture="en-US" />
</system.web>
```

Also, try specifying the format in the `ToString` method:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
```

This will display the date in the format you want. The time, however, is dependent on the server's time and won't necessarily match the time on your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

This will take server side date and time. If the server is in USA and if you are in India then you will get 12 hours difference. To solve this create a hidden input field and then wire a Javascript routine to the onsubmit event for the form. This routine would populate the hidden field with the time on the client machine.

The hidden field can used with ASP.NET by using the HTML control "HtmlInputHidden" class. You just give you input control a runat="server" attribute like any other server side control.

The server can then read out this time when the form posts back. You could even wrap this up in a server control if you need to do this in a number of places.

```
var now = new Date();
now.format("dd/M/yy h:mm tt");
```

Copy this date time to a hidden field which have runat="server" property and take that value from server.